# bluemix server gives SQLGrammarException in MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp, ibm-cloud

[![out put from cf logs app-name --recent
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRh1V.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRh1V.jpg)I have developed a spring/hibernate-MySQL in backend based application. I have tested the application in the local machine successfully. But when I uploaded the app into IBM bluemix, there is exceptions everywhere when I am accessing service-->Dao methods. It says org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException stating the message like " SELECT command denied to user 'username@75.126.83.16'. Interstingly, when I put a normal JSP without Hibernate/spring Dao but by using the same connection string, that works.

```
Here is the spring-config.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan     base-package="pojos" />
    <bean id="adminService" class="pojos.AdminService">
      <property name="adminDao" ref="adminDao" />
    </bean>
   .. Other Service class  bean's info....
 <bean id="adminDao" class="pojos.AdminDao">
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="fieldOfficerDao" class="pojos.FieldOfficerDao">
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="questionMasterDao" class="pojos.QuestionMasterDao">
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>
 .. Other Dao class  bean's info....
    <bean id="sessionFactory"      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
   <property name="mappingResources">
   <list>
   <value>pojos/Admin.hbm.xml </value>
   ... And other hbm files...

 </list>
 </property>
 <property name="hibernateProperties">
 <props>
 <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
 </props>
 </property>
 </bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.155.247.251:3307/<DB-Name>" />
    <property name="username" value="<DB-User-Name>" />
    <property name="password" value="<DB-Password>" />


</bean>

<bean id="dbUtil"
    class="pojos.DbUtil"
    init-method="initialize">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Have you used your user name (obtained from the credentials) or "username" as shown?

Comment: hi data_henrik, Yes I have used the original credential as given by bluemix phpMyAdmin service.. Not <DB-Name>,<DB-user-name> or <DB-Password>..

Comment: Hi, are you able to debug the query sent by Hibernate?

Comment: Are you seeing in the error messages the ip address 75.126.83.16 ? That doesn't seem like the correct one

Comment: @v.bontempi and whitfiea , I have added the screenshot image from the output of >cf logs appname --recent

Comment: Hello, check the IP configured on pushed configuration for hibernate, on your screenshot I found the following IP address:
169.53.230.137

Check you are using the right parameters to connect to mysql, you can retrieve the parameters to use from your application overview page, in mysql service box.

Comment: @v.bontempi, There is no problem in my connection string as I have used a JSP to test by using JDBC code and by using the same connection string in getConnection() of DriverManager and the is showing the result without having any permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed catalog attribute from class tag of each .hbm.xml files. That attribute is optional and it contains schema name of mysQL.
Previously it was

```
<class name="pojos.Admin" table="admin" catalog="merca">
```

But Now It is

```
<class name="pojos.Admin" table="admin">
```